# Run own spring library without main class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have create a spring library which other apps can use.Below is the working code which i can in other apps as maven dependency.
My question is how can I run the library without the client,since the library doesnt have main method.

```
    @Component
    public class MyService {
        
        
        public String logError(String s ) {
        return "Hello World";
        }
        }

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.custom.lib.config.MyLibConfig")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.custom.lib.config.MyLibConfig")
@EntityScan("com.custom.lib.config.MyLibConfig")
public class MyLibConfig {
    
}
```

I have META-INF folder in the library code

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.custom.lib.config.MyLibConfig
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I run the library without the client"? If it's a library it doesn't run by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write spring.factories file and you can run library from file. when spring scans libraries it automatically run classes defined in META-INF/spring.factories file. You can easily search in google about spring.factories. of course you have add dependecy to your mvn or gradle file